# Is it possible to make a SWC library in Actionscript 2?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

Is there a way to publish Actionscript 2 code in a precompiled library file just like a swc in Actionscript 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, kind of. Read the details in the fantastic [Essential Actionscript 2](http://books.google.de/books?id=wQlYlMuTbwYC&lpg=PT471&ots=f99U6ds4JN&dq=as2%20intrinsic%20essential%20actionscript%202&pg=PT356#v=onepage&q&f=false) book.